# Assign multiple properties of an object with primeng's p-dropdown

Tags: html, angular, typescript, primeng

I have an object like this assigned to the ngmodel:

```
export class operator {
  id: string;
  name: string;
  numUser: number;
  storeName: string;
  storeCode: number;
  activeOn: string;
}
```

and on my dropdown i'm assigning a list of objects like this (I'll call it "option" for now):

```
[
  {
    "storeCode": 2,
    "storeName": "storeName",
    "dateOfRegistration": "12/12/12",
    "inHbltAtuCrra": "string1",
    "inNegoPmt": "string2"
  },
]
```

So, in my html I want to, if this 'option' is selected, assign storeCode and storeName to the Operator object. Is there even a way to do that? I couldn't find anything, just one property with `[(ngModel)]="operator.storeCode"`.

My p-dropdown:

```
  <p-dropdown
    [showClear]="true"
    [options]="stores"
    [(ngModel)]="operator.storeCode"
    [filter]="true"
    optionLabel="storeName"
    optionValue="storeCode"
    filterBy="storeName"
    placeholder="Choose store"
  >
  </p-dropdown>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Delete the `optionValue` line and the value will be the entire object by default.

```html
  <p-dropdown
    [showClear]="true"
    [options]="stores"
    [(ngModel)]="operator"
    [filter]="true"
    optionLabel="storeName"
    filterBy="storeName"
    placeholder="Choose store"
  >
  </p-dropdown>
```

If you only need a few properties use the `onChange` event

```html
  <p-dropdown
    [showClear]="true"
    [options]="stores"
    (onChange)="onChange($event)"
    [filter]="true"
    optionLabel="storeName"
    filterBy="storeName"
    placeholder="Choose store"
  >
  </p-dropdown>
```

Then in the component.ts

```js
onChange(op: operator){
  this.operator.storeCode = op.storeCode;
  this.operator.storeName = op.storeName;
}
```

Comment: I know, but what if I don't need the other properties, only 2 or 3 and assing to the right places on my ngmodel? If I do it like you said it will insert an entire object to my ngmodel

Comment: Instead of `[(ngModel)]="operator"` you can use `(onChange)="onChangeFn($event)"` this will pass the object to a function, where you can extract what properties you need.